# Kendo DatePicker placeholder

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

May I know is there any way to configure the placeholder for DatePicker to dd/mm/yyyy instead of day/month/year?

Currently from here

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/formats/

I have ran the code and changed to dd/mm/yyyy format

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 example-col">
<p>Select a long date:</p>
 <kendo-datepicker
  [format]="'dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss'"
  [value]="value">
 </kendo-datepicker>
</div>
```

But the default is always showing the entire word.

Below image is an example
[image]

Comment: can you provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? With https://stackblitz.com editor for instance.

Comment: Hi @ForestG thanks for the comments.
From here
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/formats/ there is a "Run Code" that opens up a sandbox. If you clear the date in the input field the placeholder will show "day/month/year", but I am looking for the placeholder to be "dd/mm/yyyy" instead. Apologies, I am very new to these plunkr items still..

Answer (score 1):

Check the DateInputs `placeholder option if you want to control the input placeholder presentation.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/dateinput/placeholders/

Using the `[placeholder]="'short'"` property will convert the full length placeholder to narrower one.

[image]

If the `MM/dd/yyyy` placeholder is a must, then refer to the custom placeholder configuration shown in the same `Placeholders` documentation section.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 example-col">
     <p>Custom defined format descriptions</p>
     <kendo-dateinput format="G"
       [formatPlaceholder]="{
         year: 'y', month: 'M', day: 'd',
         hour: 'h', minute: 'm', second: 's'
       }"
     ></kendo-dateinput>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

`format="dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: Hi crunch. Thanks for the prompt response. I have made changes to the format. While it changes the input format, it doesn't change the placeholder format which currently always shows the full word.

example in the image provided after edit. 

dd/mm/yyyy will allow 15/09/1988 input, but when cleared it will show "day/month/year" instead of "dd/mm/yyyy" so was wondering if there are any ways to change this place holder.